# Ingresar un dato por base de datos que solo aparezca una vez para un criterio en particular

Tags: mysql

¡Saludos a todos!

Tengo una duda de base de datos... soy una principiante en esto y quisiera saber como solucionar este asunto que les comento.

Resulta que estoy creando una base de datos para una tarea que tengo. El caso de la tarea es referente a la gestión de las calificaciones de los alumnos de una universidad. Tengo dos tablas que debo unir, ellas son "Carrera" y "Asignatura" que tienen entre ambas una relación muchos a muchos. Para romper esta relación cree una tabla llamada "PensumEstudios" que une las dos claves primarias de las tablas que les he mencionado primeramente.

Sin embargo, no hallo como hacer para que cuando ingrese una asignatura se me muestre ***una sola vez*** en el pensum de una carrera, porque puede presentarse el caso que una misma asignatura pueda ser vista en el pensum de varias carreras. Les dejo por acá el bosquejo de lo que llevo para que vean qué tengo, porque lo que llevo planteado me está permitiendo introducir una asignatura muchas veces dentro de una misma carrera.

Agradecería muchísimo si me pudieran orientar sobre el error que tengo porque ya no lo veo! jeje! ¡Graciassss!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz que la clave primaria de la tabla **PensumEstudios** sean los campos **idCarrera** e **idAsignatura**, de ese modo evitas que puedan haber dos registros con la misma carrera y la misma asignatura

Comment: Muchas gracias! no sabes cuanto me ayudó tu consejo!!! miiill graciasss!

Comment: ¡Encantado pero deberías marcar la respuesta como válida!